# Define sidebar based on route in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i wonder how i can show different sidebars with different routes.

Eg:

i have two different sidebar component like:

`<SidebarA />` and `<SidebarB />` when user in root `'/'` i wan't to show `<SidebarA />` when in `'/list'` i wan't to show `<SidebarB />`

i did with condition based on `window.location.pathname` 
But after upgrade version of my React and react-router my `window.location.pathname` not changing if i don't refresh page.

My code is now like that :

```
  <div className="columns">
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
        <Route exact path="/list" component={List} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </div>

     {window.location.pathname === "/" ? (
          <SidebarA />
        ) : null}

{window.location.pathname === "/list" ? (
          <SidebarB />
        ) : null}
```

have some brilliant method for this?

Answer (score 1):

You should make a Higher Order component
Layout, That accepts following props,

- children: ReactNode;
- variant?: 'A' | 'B';

And then have a check op in your Layout Component Like

```
const Layout = ({props}) => {
  return (
    {
    props.variant === 'A' ?
     //Code For SideBarA
    :
     //Code for SideBarB
    }
    {children}
  )
}

export default Home ;
```

And then wrap your component with whatever side bar you want to use.

```
const Main= () => {
  return (
    <Layout variant='A'>
      <div>
        i'm Main
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to create wrapper component to manage it

```
class MainWrapper extends Component {
  render () {
    return <div className="main-layout">
       <div className="content">{this.props.childern}</div>
       <div className="sidebar"><SideBar></SidebarA></div>
     </div>
  }
}
```

export default MainWrapper;

Now Main component

```
import MainWrapper from 'MainWrapper';
    class Main extends Component {
      return {
        <MainWrapper> /* your main compnent element */</MainWrapper>
      }
    }
export default Main;
```

The same you can create few wrappers for each situation

Answer (score 0):

Make route.js

```
export default [
{
    path: "/",
    exact: true,
    sidebar: SideBarA
    component: Main
}, {
    path: "/List",
    exact: true,
    sidebar: SideBarB,
    component: List
}]
```

And in your App.js

```
class App extends Component {

render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                {routes.map((route, index) => {
                    return (
                        <Route
                            key={index}
                            path={route.path}
                            exact={route.exact}
                            component={
                                return (
                                    <>
                                    <route.sidebar/>
                                    <route.component {...props} />
                                    </>
                              )}
                        />
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

}